# "Mixed content blocked" ;page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint with https

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, https, vercel, mixed-content

I am using vercel to host my app and gcp to host my api

After a day of torturing, I notice that the mixed content is about my api being http, instead of https, which they also refer it as ssl, which I am not so familiar with it too.

So, luckily, the api is controlled by me and I allowed https traffic on my gcp setting already.

[image]

Then, I try it on Postman with https prefix, But I still get this saying error in ssl

[image]

I wonder if it is to do with my API code setting or there are still sth I was missing

My Node js api code, port is 8080 already. And testing is only work with http still.

```
const app = require("./app");
require("dotenv").config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Do not try to configure HTTP and HTTPS to use the same port number. By convention port 8080 is HTTP. Use something 443 or 8443 for HTTPS. Note: your node.js code does not support HTTPS only HTTP.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for sharing your experience. I have heard that I can achieve https request by either changing my code to accept https or setting up some ngix server. Actually I dont have idea on how to do it on both ways. May I know which way would you suggest me to go for before diving it into it.

Comment: In today's world, you need to support both HTTP and HTTPS. You can do that either in your node.js program or by using Nginx or similar as a proxy. Nginx then handles HTTP and HTTPS and proxies requests to your node.js application via HTTP. Google search, there are many tutorials to explain the details and how to configure everything.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for comments, Since I see that using changing code approach on nodes JS only requires few lines of code, may I know is there any reason to use nginx over code changing?

Comment: There are many reasons to use Nginx in front of your application. Security, performance, much easier SSL deployment, etc. Google search for articles.

Comment: @JohnHanley , thanks for pointing it out. But Is it really easy to set up ngix for routing? Seems I need to set up DNS, Class A type and so on... It seems it need to go so far to achieve my goals.... or I am tracking the wrong path

Comment: You must do those items no matter what you deploy. DNS is the phonebook that links your domain name to your site.